# Seeking polygon data of wine (viticulture) areas and their main grape or varietal

Tags: data

Where is coordinate data on the geographic boundaries of wine (vitaculture) areas and their main type of wine (grape or varietal)? a GIS shapefile or geoJSON file format would be perfect.

Ideally I would like the **polygon areas** for wines of USA or Europe along with a few attributes corresponding to each area.

But even just data for at least one major country or varietal would be nice.

I can handle the geographic coordinates in any format.

Comment: What kind of attributes do you need?

Comment: @underdark Best attribute: type of wine (grape or varietal). Nice attributes to have: Place name, elevation, soil.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 9):

The Corine project features a "Vineyards" dataset for Europe: http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2000-clc2000-seamless-vector-database-2

Comment: I opened the dbf. There are 20,000 polygon areas of vineyards accross Europe--very comprehensive-- but I did not see any attribute information associated with the vineyard areas, just alpha-numeric ids. Any chance you know where the data that links to these alpha-numeric ids might reside?

Comment: Corine is a land cover project classifying satellite imagery. I don't think there is any additional attribute information available through this source.

Answer (score 3):

If you have any experience scraping you might get the list from wikipedia and work that into something.
[Wikipedia Wine list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wine-producing_regions)

GIS is being used for the:
["Viticultural zoning system for the identification and characterisation of New Zealand Terroirs"](http://www.geo-informatics.org/publications/Viticultural%20Zoning%20for%20the%20Identification%20and%20Characterisation%20of%20NZ%20terroirs%20using%20cartographic%20data.pdf)

Perhaps the [Agricultural Census 2007](http://nationalatlas.gov/mld/agcn07.html) will have something

And finally this [KMZ](http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=313151&page=all) (which I trouble downloading) says there is a point for each country

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer to this issue, but I'll mention here the OpenWines.eu initiative (non-profit, 100% open-data oriented) that actually started to tag vineyard in OpenStreetMap adding precisions on grape varieties, vine row orientation (in degrees) and more meta data. First attempt is available on OpenWines website and OpenstreetMap's Wiki about tag `landuse=vineyard`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can visit WineMaps.com or download the "WineMaps App" to see all of the regions on the globle.

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".

Comment: Apart from the nickname that suggests so and the fact that the user has been created just for this post: do you have further indication that the OP is affiliated to the site?